# Trying to use a list into a tcolorbox with \newcommand at the preamble

Tags: xetex, lists, tcolorbox

I use the following code to have a list of exercises, each one into a tcolorbox, but I can't find a way to enumerate automatically the title of tcolorbox in the \newcommand at the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\exercise}{\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=
\begin{LARGE}
\color{purple}Exercise %<-- here I want automatically numbering%
\end{LARGE}  ,
colframe=black,colback=black!10!white,colbacktitle=black!8!white,drop shadow,
fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm,
frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
-- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
-- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
-- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
-- cycle;} }]}

\begin{document}
\exercise
random pronunciation
\end{tcolorbox}

\exercise %<-- second etc...
random pronunciation
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` package allows to automatically number its boxes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exercise}{
  enhanced,
  title=Exercise~\thetcbcounter,
  fonttitle=\LARGE\bfseries,
  coltitle=purple,
  colframe=black,
  colback=black!10!white,
  colbacktitle=black!8!white,
  drop shadow,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0.5mm,
    frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west) -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
    interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west) -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east) -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) -- cycle;} 
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
random pronunciation
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
random pronunciation
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define a counter and step it at every `exercise`.

I changed from `\newcommand` to `\newenvironment` to get a better conforming syntax.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{exercise}

\newenvironment{exercise}{%
  \stepcounter{exercise}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    title=\textcolor{purple}{Exercise \theexercise},
    colframe=black,
    colback=black!10!white,
    colbacktitle=black!8!white,
    drop shadow,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\LARGE,
    coltitle=black,
    attach boxed title to top center={
      yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
      yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
      boxed title style={
        boxrule=0.5mm,
        frame code={
          \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
            -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;
        },
        interior code={
          \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
            -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
            -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
            -- cycle;
        },
      },
    ]%
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
random pronunciation
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
random pronunciation
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]